# Aggregation of data from a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is a table in a `CSV` file format:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 35480007 | 0695388 |
| 35480007 | 0695388 |
| 35407109 | 3324741 |
| 35407109 | 3324741 |
| 35250208 | 0695388 |
| 35250208 | 6104556 |
| 86730903 | 3360935 |
| 86730903 | 3360935 |

Could you please tell me how can data aggregation be done using the `pandas` library to display information about which values from column `B` intersect with column `A`?
As a result, I need to display the following information:

The value `0695388` from column `B` corresponds to the values from column `A`: `35480007`, `35250208`, etc. duplicates from column `A` are not taken into account.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `groupby`:

```
>>> df.groupby("B")["A"].unique()
B
695388     [35480007, 35250208]
3324741              [35407109]
3360935              [86730903]
6104556              [35250208]
Name: A, dtype: object
```