# Correct display of data after aggregation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In continuation of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71147769/aggregation-of-data-from-a-csv-file)

There is a table in a `CSV` file format:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 35480007 | 0695388 |
| 35480007 | 0695388 |
| 35407109 | 3324741 |
| 35407109 | 3324741 |
| 35250208 | 0695388 |
| 35250208 | 6104556 |
| 86730903 | 3360935 |
| 86730903 | 3360935 |

By applying the code for `aggregation`:

```
df.groupby("B")["A"].unique()
```

I get the result:

```
695388     [35480007, 35250208]
3324741              [35407109]
3360935              [86730903]
6104556              [35250208]
```

Could you  tell me please, how can I apply some kind of filter so that only those values that have a value greater than `two` can be displayed: that is so:

```
695388     [35480007, 35250208]
```

and how to save the result to a file, for example in txt.

I apologize in advance if my question seemed incorrect. I am very weak in the `pandas` library.

thank you very much!

Comment: all your values have a value greater than two.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But how do I display only those rows that are more than two? I don't need the whole result.

Comment: your example doesn't have any entry with rows with more than 2 elements. It's unclear what you are asking. Please make an example of the input and desired output. And put the code that generates you data. Is this a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: the question has been edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a second to realize that what you mean is not a value greater than two, but rather a length greater than one (or greather than or equal to two).

With that said, you can use the `apply` function on your `Series` to see which rows satisfy this property

```py
grouped = df.groupby("B")["A"].unique()
has_multiple_elements = grouped.apply(lambda x: len(x)>1)
```

Which basically applies a function to each entry in your `grouped` series, and returns the following:

```py
695388      True
3324741    False
3360935    False
6104556    False
```

Now all that's left is to use these `True/False` boolean values to filter your series. Luckily, this is very simple.

```py
result = grouped[has_multiple_elements]
```

As for the second part of your question, writing this to a file can be done using the `to_csv` function:

```py
# I usually use tab separated files in case any commas appear in your data itself
result.to_csv('output.tsv', sep='\t')
```